# testdriven.net log4net console output

Tags: nunit, log4net, testdriven.net

How do I get log4net console output to show up when using TestDriven.net to run nunit tests? I'm using the ColoredConsoleAppender, and there is no log output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer. You can use the regular xml config file approach, but you need to configure a TraceAppender:

```
    <appender name="TraceAppender" type="log4net.Appender.TraceAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
     </layout>
   </appender>
```